# @viewport does not work in Safari Mobile (ipad 2)

Tags: html, css

@viewport does not work in Safari Mobile (ipad 2)

I can't use `<meta name="viewport" ... />`, I can only use css.

UserAgent : Mozilla/5.0 (ipad,...AppleWebKit/534.46...Safari/7534.48.3)

```
@-webkit-viewport {
 width: 480px;
 zoom: 2.0;
 user-zoom: zoom;
}
@-moz-viewport {
 width: 480px;
 zoom: 2.0;
 user-zoom: zoom;
}
@-ms-viewport {
 width: 480px;
 zoom: 2.0;
 user-zoom: zoom;
}
@-o-viewport {
 width: 480px;
 zoom: 2.0;
 user-zoom: zoom;
}
@viewport {
  width: 480px;
  zoom: 2.0;
  user-zoom: zoom;
}
```

Comment: As far as I am aware you must use the meta tag on Safari Mobile (iPad and iPhone safari) and the @viewport does not work without it (or at all).

Comment: where is your <meta> ??

Comment: I cant use meta tag, only css.

Comment: I don't think there is any way without it. You either need to find a way to be able to add it or use a different method for what you're trying to do.

Comment: might help : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=safari+mobile+viewport

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger your viewport somehow, via `<meta>` or `<javascript>`

[EDITED]

[original source](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3889591/Detect-and-Set-the-iPhone--iPads-Viewport-Orientation-Using-JavaScript-CSS-and-Meta-Tags.htm)

**Using JavaScript for iPhone and iPad Orientation**

The meta tags shown above work very well, however, you can also use JavaScript to do the same thing, since both the iPad and iPhone support the scripting language. The following JavaScript function detects and sets the device's viewport orientation by using the innerWidth property of the window object and setting the orient attribute of the body element regularly (in this case every 4 seconds):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var updateLayout = function() {
  if (window.innerWidth != currentWidth) {
    currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var orient = (currentWidth == 320) ? "profile" : "landscape";
    document.body.setAttribute("orient", orient);
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }
};

iPhone.DomLoad(updateLayout);
setInterval(updateLayout, 400);
</script>
```

You can place the above snippet in the HEAD of your iPhone/iPad-ready web page, and it will set the display to the appropriate orientation setting.

Comment: @jacob OP was modified AFTER posting answer.